# PL/SQL cursor not exiting when null data found

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, stringtokenizer

I have a field in a table containing 'SMITH,ALLEN,WARD,JONES'. I'm trying to read rows from table using cursor and when this particular field is found, used regexp_substr to split it using `','` as the delimiter.

Here is the code:

```
    PROCEDURE x26837a_dummy IS
    CURSOR d_cursor IS
    SELECT regexp_substr('SMITH,ALLEN,WARD,JONES', '[^,]+', 1, level)
        FROM x26837a_dummy_table
    CONNECT BY regexp_substr('SMITH,ALLEN,WARD,JONES', '[^,]+', 1, 1) IS NOT NULL
    lvar VARCHAR2(128) := '';
  BEGIN
    OPEN d_cursor;
    LOOP
      FETCH d_cursor
        INTO lvar;
      EXIT WHEN d_cursor%NOTFOUND;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lvar);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE d_cursor;
  END x26837a_dummy;
```

I want the names returned separately, so this cursor should exit after printing four values, since after that it returns null values. But `%NOTFOUND` condition doesn't exit the loop and it keeps looping. Can't seem to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is your regex expression doesn't terminate. As you point out, the cursor keeps fetching records with a null "name".

One option would be to change the test to exit the loop:

```
if lvar is null then exit; end if;
```

The other option is to fix the regex. The `CONNECT BY` clause should be:

```
  CONNECT BY regexp_substr('SMITH,ALLEN,WARD,JONES', '[^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL;
  -- change this ------------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works-> if lvar is null then exit; end if; . The level parameter returns all the sets but I need only one, that is the reason I went with '1'.